# What happens if the ball returns to the player's side of the court in tennis?

Tags: rules, trivia, tennis

What happens if a tennis player hits the ball with a very large amount of spin and after the first bounce the ball returns to his side of the court?

For example, in this [video](http://ilbuzz.it.eurosport.com/stars/caro-paire-ci-spieghi-come-hai-fatto-4065/?_ga=1.102619529.947726679.1438592063) (the 3rd replay is the best) it is possible to see that the ball is very close to returning to Paire's court.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a player stretch into opponent's court to play a shot?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7408/can-a-player-stretch-into-opponents-court-to-play-a-shot)

Comment: In particular, see point 2 in [pacoverflow's answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/7409/6126) to that question.

Comment: The answer is on the other question.. BUT, this question is very different from the other.. I would like to copy the other answer (point 2) because it looks correct to me..

Comment: @gbianchi the question are very different. That reply works also for this question, but is not correct to close this question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us say Player 1 hits the ball with a huge amount of spin, causing it to bounce in Player 2's side of the court and return back over the net to Player 1's side. If Player 2 is unable to reach over the net and play the ball, Player 1 gets the point. If Player 2 is able to reach over the net and play the ball without him, his clothing or any item he may be carrying touching the net, net post or the ground on Player 1's side of the court, Player 2 has made a legitimate return and play resumes normally.

[USTA](http://www.usta.com/Improve-Your-Game/Player-to-Player/Rules/Reaching_over_the_net/)

> If the spin or wind brings the ball back over the net to the side of the player(s) who hit the shot, the opponent(s) may then reach over the net and play the ball.

Comment: I agree that when the ball would return back on P1 side and bounce there, it would be P2’s fault per rule 24.b (“before it bounces twice”). However, I wonder what rule would govern if the ball bounced from P2 side, returned to P1 side and _then touched P1’s racket_ (per my reading it would be P1’s fault if it touched P1’s body per 24.i, without regard to the fact the ball came from the other side untouched by P2).

Comment: @Mormegil If it touches P1's racket while it is still in play after his last shot he loses the point.